# Building meta-virtualization layer in yocto

Tags: linux, docker, yocto, lxc

I am trying to add the meta-virtualization layer in my yocto project. The layer depends on openembedded-core and multiple layers provided by meta-openembedded. Following is the structure of my bblayers.conf file after adding the meta-virtualization layer and it's dependencies.

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-yocto \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-oe \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-virtualization \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-networking \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-filesystems \
/home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-python \
"
```

However, when I try to build docker present in the meta-virtualization layer, I encounter the following error

```
WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-16.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |####################################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 1078 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/tcltk/tk_8.6.6.bb                                                        | ETA:  --:--:--
ERROR: ParseError at /home/mshehery/Downloads/git/Yocto/poky/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/libqmi/libqmi_1.16.0.bb:12: Could not inherit file classes/bash-completion.bbclass
```

If I am not wrong, the current versions of the yocto project use openembedded as their build system. So, is there any need to integrate the openembedded-core into my yocto project to add the meta-virtualization layer, or is it already present in the yocto project by default?

Comment: Could you add which versions/branches you're using? (For all your included layers). No, you don't need to add openembedded-core, that layer is the first one in your list (`meta`).

Comment: @Anders The version of yo0cto is Yocto 2.2 (Morty). The layers I have downloaded form the following link
(https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/)

Comment: I am able to build the meta-virtualization layer using oe-core successfully, however the problem arises when I try to add the layers into my yocto project.

Comment: If you remove `meta-virtualization` can you build the rest then? `bash-completions.bbclass` should be in `meta/classes`...

Comment: I was able to build core-image-minimal image before adding the meta-virtualization layer and its dependencies. The absence of bash-completions.bbclass is only one of the errors. I can add this file form the openembedded-core/meta/classes directory into poky/meta/classes. But then it starts showing multiple Syntax errors where bitbake is unable to parse certain portions of the recipes. The real issue is integrating meta-virtualization layer with poky which I am unable to do.

Comment: Strange, `bash-completions.bbclass` is in oe-core (in Morty), and thus part of YP Morty, http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/bash-completion.bbclass?h=morty. If you lack that file, double check with poky release you're actually running.

Comment: I have successfully built the 'core-image-minimal' image after adding the meta-virtualization layer and its dependencies. I was using their master branch, whereas the correct approach was to use the 'Morty' branch. However, when I try to build docker now it throws the error
**ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'docker'**

Comment: Well,`docker` should be part of the Morty branch of meta-virtualization. What does `ls meta-virtualization/recipes-containers` give you? And then `ls meta-virtualization/recipes-containers/docker`?

Comment: The first command returns **cgroup-lite  containerd  criu  docker  docker-registry  lxc  runc** and the second returns **docker_git.bb  files**

Comment: I am trying to separately build docker, and according to my knowledge(I don't know if I am right) **bitbake docker** should work?

Comment: Well, that you found `docker_git.bb` means that you should be able to run `bitbake docker`, as long as `meta-virtualization` is in your `bblayers.conf`.

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the help. Successfully built docker. Forgot to add the meta-virtualization layer in bblayers.conf by mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short summary of the discussion:

- Use the same release branch for all your layers (unless you **really** know what you do.
- Check that all your layers are activated in `bblayers.conf`.

Comment: I am getting the following error when trying to build docker on fido version of yocto. Can you help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976123/building-docker-on-yocto)

Comment: See my comment on that thread. Basically, if you want help, you need to add the actual error message.