# Building docker on yocto

Tags: linux, docker, yocto, lxc

I am getting the following error when trying to build docker on yocto

```
ERROR: Task 104 (/var/mshehery/Release_7.3/sheheryar/yocto/fido/meta/meta-virtualization/recipes-devtools/go/golang-cross_1.3.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

I am using the 'fido' branch of yocto, meta-virtualization and meta-openembedded. Can anyone elaborate the issue?

Apart from the above Error, I am also getting some Log Data. I am posting the portions which might give an insight into the problem

Log data follows:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| GOARCH i586
| CC_FOR_TARGET gcc
| + set -e
| + [ ! -f run.bash ]
| + uname
| + grep gold.* 2\.20
| + ld --version
| + [ -d /selinux -a -f /selinux/booleans/allow_execstack -a -x /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled ]
| + [ -d /sys/fs/selinux -a -f /sys/fs/selinux/booleans/allow_execstack -a -x /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled ]
| + uname -s
| + [ Linux == GNU/kFreeBSD ]
| ./make.bash: 104: [: Linux: unexpected operator
| + rm -f ./pkg/runtime/runtime_defs.go
| + echo # Building C bootstrap tool.
| # Building C bootstrap tool.
| + echo cmd/dist
| cmd/dist
| + cd ..
| + pwd
| + export GOROOT=/var/mshehery/Documents/git/fido/build/tmp/work/x86_64-poky-linux/golang-cross/1.3-r0/go
| + GOROOT_FINAL=/var/mshehery/Documents/git/fido/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/go
| + DEFGOROOT=-DGOROOT_FINAL="/var/mshehery/Documents/git/fido/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/go"
| + mflag=
| + uname
| + [ Linux == Darwin ]
| ./make.bash: 124: [: Linux: unexpected operator
| + type -t gcc
| + type -t clang
| + [ -z gcc  -a -z -t: not found
| gcc is /usr/bin/gcc -a -n -t: not found
| clang: not found ]
| + gcc -O2 -Wall -Werror -o cmd/dist/dist -Icmd/dist -DGOROOT_FINAL="/var/mshehery/Documents/git/fido/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/go" cmd/dist/arm.c cmd/dist/buf.c cmd/dist/build.c cmd/dist/buildgc.c cmd/dist/buildgo.c cmd/dist/buildruntime.c cmd/dist/goc2c.c cmd/dist/main.c cmd/dist/plan9.c cmd/dist/unix.c cmd/dist/windows.c
| + ./cmd/dist/dist env -p
| go tool dist: unknown $GOARCH i586
| + echo FAIL=true
| + eval FAIL=true
| + FAIL=true
| + [ true = true ]
| + exit 1
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /var/mshehery/Documents/git/fido/build/tmp/work/x86_64-poky-linux/golang-cross/1.3-r0/temp/log.do_compile.31971)
```

Comment: Well, could you give us the error message? The line above only tells us that something went wrong while compiling the go cross-compiler.

Comment: @Anders This is the only Error message printed. However, I am also getting a very lengthy Log Data printed along with the error. Would you like to take a look at the Log Data?

Comment: Well, you should post it, or at least the parts of the log that shows the error.

Comment: @Anders Kindly check the edited post. The Log Data might be useful.

Comment: @Anders I have added the entire Log Data. See if you can identify the issue.

Comment: Well, you have a few errors in that log. I've never built Go, so I'm not able to look that much further into this. You have a few tests in that makefile that isn't really valid (unexpected operator). Check them. Also, check why the build complains about gcc. Also, don't open a new question for the same issue; and always post the actual error message...

Answer (score 0):

> go tool dist: unknown $GOARCH i586

This is your answer. Please check [available GOARCH values](https://gist.github.com/asukakenji/f15ba7e588ac42795f421b48b8aede63).

In case you need more help, you need to clarify **bitbake** arguments that had been used. And layers/recipes also:

```
bitbake-layers show-layers
```

Answer (score -2):

When you `docker build`you get various layers.

You can run the last image created before the failure, example

`---> Using cache
 ---> a03f050edd2f
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT`

in that case

`docker run -it a03f050edd2f bash`

and then issue the command that fails, and see what happens

If this is not secret, post a reproducer, the Dockerfile..

Comment: I am building docker with the command `bitbake docker` in yocto. I need to build docker for an embedded device. Doesn't the command `docker run -it a03f050edd2f bash` requires docker to be installed already?

Comment: yes you need docker installed to run `docker build`

Comment: I am trying to build docker through the meta-virtualization layer which allows constructing OE based virtualized solutions. I am afraid I cannot install docker prior to building it for my embedded device.

Comment: @user2915097 I believe you didn't read the question carefully. 
He isn't building Docker image. He is building docker itself.