# How to add xvisor support in to yocto

Tags: yocto

I am currently working on Yocto, want to integrate xvisor hypervisor into Yocto.

I wrote a recipe for xvisor, but how can I tell to the system like I am doing for

linux and uboot using PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel and PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot

I tried with PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/xvisor, but it is not taking.

How to compile the code, i.e do_compile()

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yocto Documentations](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_PROVIDER) PREFERRED_PROVIDER's usage is as below.

*`If multiple recipes provide an item, this variable determines which recipe should be given preference.You should always suffix the variable with the name of the provided item, and you should set it to the PN of the recipe to which you want to give precedence.`*

You simply cannot use PREFERRED_PROVIDERS_virtual/xvisor unless meta-virtualization layer is added.

If you want to add hypervisor support, you have to use meta-virtualization layer in your yoctobuild.

[Reference to start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938892/building-meta-virtualization-layer-in-yocto)